# Problema ao persistir um relacionamento

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entidade-relacionamento

Tenho 2 entidades, a SubModelo possui uma lista de possíveis Opcionais.

Fiz uma relação OneToMany unidirecional, quando eu faço qualquer persistência na entidade SubModelo que a lista de Opcionais esta vazia o Hibernate faz tranquilamente, mas sem têm que incluir/editar o relacionamento dela com a Opcionais daí ocorre o erro.

A forma que eu fiz este relacionamento esta errada?

```java
@Entity
public class SubModelo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @Size(max = 30)
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @Size (max = 1)
    private String portas;

    @NotNull
    @Size (max = 9)
    private String motor;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated
    private Combustivel comb;

    @NotNull
    private boolean automatico;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "SUBMODELO_TEM_OPCS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SUBMODELO_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OPCIONAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Opcional> opc;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Opcional implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @Size(max = 35)
    @NotNull(message = "Nome do Opcional Deve Ser Informado!")
    private String nome;

    @Column
    @Size(max = 150)
    @NotNull(message = "Descrição Detalhada Deve Ser Informado!")
    private String descricao;

    @Column(length = 1)
    @NotNull
    private String nivel;

    @Column(length = 3)
    private String icon;
}
```

O erro:

```
23:55:03,875 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SubModeloService for method public br.com.ozelo.entidades.SubModelo br.com.ozelo.servico.SubModeloService.novoSubModelo(br.com.ozelo.entidades.SubModelo): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional.id] by reflection for persistent property [br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional#id] : ABS
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional.id] by reflection for persistent property [br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional#id] : ABS
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
        ... 103 more
```

Comment: poste o outro lado do relacionamento, no caso a classe Opcional.